# Overlap When Painting Stripes: Can I Sand?

Tags: walls, painting

I'm painting a three-stripe pattern across the length of my wall, and I had a question about whether I could sand down the overlapping areas.

The stripe consists of a 21" green stripe with two 3" stripes (white and dark grey) bordering it. It goes green--white--dark grey from bottom to top. The walls are a light grey/taupe color. We painted the top and bottom of the wall light grey, and then we measured and painted a swath of white. Next we will paint the grey and green and ta da, the white becomes a stripe.

So to my question. When we painted the white, you could see the buildup under it when you look closely. It's not super obvious, but my OCD had taken over. Before I paint the other stripes, can I tape them off and sand down the areas that will be painted? I just want to whittle down the paint a little so it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, no problem there as long as you get what you want. Or, you can very lightly & precisely cut or score it along a straight-edge with a razor blade & peel it off. Or, even very carefully paint white over any bleeding fissures.

Comment: Good ideas. For all of them, make sure you experiment to get the technique down. With sanding in particular, the grit of the paper will affect the final texture and gloss of the paint in the sanded area, and if you're using a glossy paint it could come out looking dull.